# Flask image variable is "sticking"

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app that works the first time, after that the html always show the first predicted image even though the new predicted image is written to the folder

I have tried deleting the image from the upload folder, but the original prediction is staying.

Below is my flask app

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = ''
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['jpg', 'png'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in 
    ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():

if request.method == 'POST':
    # check if the post request has the file part
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)

    file = request.files['file']

    # if user does not select file, browser also
    # submit an empty part without filename
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No selected file')
        return redirect(request.url)

    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        #filename = file.filename
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        image = open_image(filename)
        image_url = url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename)
        think = learn.predict(image)
        think_np = np.array(think[1])
        think_np.shape = (256,256)
        think_np = think_np.astype(int)
        think_np[think_np > 0] = 255
        think_im = Image.fromarray((think_np).astype('uint8'), mode='L')
        think_im.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'think2_im.png'))
        think_im_url = url_for('uploaded_file', filename='think2_im.png')
        print(think_im_url)
        #image.show(y=learn.predict(image)[0])
        return '''<h1>The cell image is:</h1>
        <img src= "{}" height = "85" width="200"/>
        <h1>The cell segmentation is:</h1>
        <img src= "{}" height = "85" width="200"/>'''.format(image_url, think_im_url)


return '''
<!doctype html>
<title>Upload new File</title>
<h1>Upload an image of Cells</h1>
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
  <input type=file name=file>
  <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
'''


@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
```

The first time I run this everything works great.  But, if I run again, the think_im_url always shows the first predicted image.  Even if I restart the kernel.  Even if I go into the upload folder and delete the image.  Also, though, the predicted image written to the upload folder is the correct (new) predicted image.  Just what is showing in the HTML always stays the same.

If I go into the code and change the name, i.e. change "think2_img.png" to "think3_img.png", then the process starts again.  The first time works great, but even though new predictions overwrite the "think" prediction in the upload folder, the HTML only shows the original prediction.

The image_URL changes each time like it is supposed to.

Comment: Could it be a cache issue? Have you tried force reloading the page in the browser (normally Ctrl+F5)?

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, that was it, although to just clear the cache for that particular page I had to follow this:  https://techzillo.com/clear-cache-one-website-chrome/.  But, that did it, thanks!  Works now